# Injecting object from depended module in Android Dagger

Tags: android, dagger

I have two module, `AppModule` and `SplashViewModule`

For `AppModule`:

```
@Module
public final class AppModule {
    @NonNull
    private final MyApplication mApp;

    public AppModule(@NonNull MyApplication app) {
        mApp = app;
    }

    @Provides
    public Context provideAppContext() {
        return mApp;
    }

    @Provides
    public MyApplication provideApp() {
        return mApp;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public UserManager provideUserManager() {
        return new UserManager();
    }
}
```

For `SplashviewModule`

```
@Module
public final class SplashViewModule {

    @Inject
    UserManager mUserManager;

    @Provides
    public SplashInteractor provideInteractor() {
        return new SplashInteractorImpl(mUserManager);
    }

    @Provides
    public PresenterFactory<SplashPresenter> providePresenterFactory(@NonNull final SplashInteractor interactor) {
        return new PresenterFactory<SplashPresenter>() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public SplashPresenter create() {
                return new SplashPresenterImpl(interactor);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And I inject these to my activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void setupComponent(@NonNull AppComponent parentComponent) {
    DaggerSplashViewComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(parentComponent)
            .splashViewModule(new SplashViewModule())
            .build()
            .inject(this);
}
```

But this does not work. The `UserManager` would be null. How can I get the singleton instance of `UserManager` created by `AppModule` and inject it to `SplashViewModule`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare `UserManager mUserManager;` in `SplashViewModule`. Just add a `UserManager` parameter for the method `provideInteractor`.

```
@Provides
public SplashInteractor provideInteractor(UserManager userManager) {
    return new SplashInteractorImpl(userManager);
}
```